# Writing into XML with an XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml

I'm writing data into an XML file like the following:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string xmlFile = Server.MapPath("savedata.xml");
      XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(xmlFile, null);

      writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
      writer.Indentation = 3;

      writer.WriteStartDocument();

     //Write the root element
     writer.WriteStartElement("items");

     //Write sub-elements
     writer.WriteElementString("title", "First book title");
     writer.WriteElementString("title", "Second book title");
     writer.WriteElementString("title", "Third book title");

     // end the root element
     writer.WriteEndElement();

     //Write the XML to file and close the writer
     writer.Close();  
  }
```

However this writes the XML with the following structure:

```
<items>
   <title>First book title</title>
   <title>Second book title</title>
<items>
```

But I need an XML file with the following structure:

```
<Symbols>
  <Symbol ExecutionSymbol="ATT" Name="AT&amp;T"></Symbol>
  <Symbol ExecutionSymbol="MSFT" Name="Microsoft"></Symbol>
</Symbols>
```

Comment: Also, you should not be using `new XmlTextWriter()`. It has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead. Also, surround your writer in a `using` block.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you did not understand me correctly. The second example of XML structure was just a dummy data. I wanted to give you an idea on what exactly I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at other methods of XmlWriter. Obviously you want to write attributes instead of elements. So you have to use WriteAttribute* methods instead of WriteElement* methods.

Comment: Would be grateful if you could give an example, or a link to an article, etc.

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out already :) Thanks for the help!